# Host required for running Windows 2008 x64 Microsoft VPC

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-xp, 32-bit

I need to run a x64 version of Windows in order to run SharePoint 2010.

Question is:

- Can I run this on a machine that is running a x32 bit version of Windows?
- Can I run this on a machine that has a x32 bit CPU?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It strongly depends on the virtualization platform you want to use.

With VMWare, you can run a x64 guest on a x86 operating system, provided you have a x64 CPU and it supports Intel VT extensions (or their AMD equivalent).

There's no way (I know of) you can run a x64 system, be it guest or host, if you don't have an actual x64 CPU.

Answer (score 1):

You specifically mentioned Microsoft Virtual PC, which doesn't support 64-bit guests at all, regardless of whether the host is 32- or 64-bit.  As the other person answered, you'll want VMWare for this.